# Application Insights monitor functions: How to skip failed retries

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I config Application Insights to monitor function. My function is trigger by the queue. I know function can retry 5 times if there are some errors.

For example, if send a message to queue, the function receive and process it, but the first 3 processings failed, the 4th retried succeeded. so this message was processed successful. In Application Insight, I hope its success rate is 100%. because this messgae is processed 4 times.
So final success rate is 1/4 = 25%.

I would like to know how to use the final success of the event as the standard instead of counting every failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I created Queue trigger in visual studio. The queue message which we send that can be triggered in the console and it will be monitor by the application insights which we added to the function app.

I have tried as per your info, Check below.

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
ILogger functionLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Function1");

            functionLogger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

            if (_failureCount < 4)
            {
                _failureCount++;
                throw new System.Exception("Intentional failure");
            }

            // Track a custom event
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent("QueueTriggered", new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "QueueName", "testmessagequeue" },
                { "MessageContent", myQueueItem }
            });

            // Log that the function has finished processing the message
            functionLogger.LogInformation($"Function finished processing message: {myQueueItem}");
     }
  }
```

These are the results which I get.
[image]

[image]
[image]

> I would like to know how to use the final success of the event as the standard instead of counting every failure.

You can use the **Success** field in the telemetry data to track the **final success status** of an event in Application Insights. Instead of incrementing a counter for each failure, you can set the Success field to false for each failed event and to true for the final successful event.

This is the code which works for me.

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("testmessagequeue", Connection = "teststorage0121")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
            configuration.InstrumentationKey = "****";
            TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

            ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            ILogger functionLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Function1");

            functionLogger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

            // Track a custom event with Success field set to false for failed events
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent("QueueTriggered", new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "QueueName", "testmessagequeue" },
                { "MessageContent", myQueueItem }
            }, new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                { "Success", 0 } // set Success field to false for failed events
            });

            if (myQueueItem.Contains("retry")) // simulate a failure for the first 3 processings
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Simulated failure");
            }

            // Log that the function has finished processing the message
            functionLogger.LogInformation($"Function finished processing message: {myQueueItem}");

            // Track a custom event with Success field set to true for final successful event
            telemetryClient.TrackEvent("MessageProcessedSuccessfully", new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "MessageContent", myQueueItem }
            }, new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, double>
            {
                { "Success", 1 } // set Success field to true for final successful event
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The application works fine.
[image]
Then, I have sent a message from the queue to trigger the result in console.
[image]

Iam able see the desired result.
[image]
I have filtered by the **QueueTriggered** and **MessageProcessedSuccessfully** event names and used the Success field to track the success rate of the final event.
[image]
We can check the Success rate below.
[image]